# SSL error on macOS Monterey when using python urllib via RDFLib

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, macos-monterey

So I have been getting the following error when trying to request an HTTPS resource using the python RDFLib module:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>
```

What I have tried thus far:

1. Installed Python 3.10.4 from python.org
2. Executed the Install Certificates.command successfully tried the request again and I get the same error
3. Created a virtual environment using `python3 -m venv venv` which is based on Python 3.10.4, activated it, updated certifi just in case using `pip3 install certifi --upgrade` as it was suggested in other posts, and tried the request again and I still got the error.
4. Out of desperation, I did a clean install of Monterey and still get the same error

So it appears that the issue is that the certificates are not actually getting installed even though the command executes successfully:

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.10/Install\ Certificates.command ; exit;                
meh@iMac ~ % /Applications/Python\ 3.10/Install\ Certificates.command ; exit;
 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2021.10.8)
 -- removing any existing file or link
 -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle
 -- setting permissions
 -- update complete

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

I have actually been trying to solve this for many months, coming back and trying again and again but I can't seem to find a solution.

This seems to be a common issue that is usually resolved by executing the Install Certificates.command but that simply doesn't work for me. It's worth noting that I have the same issue on a brand new MacBook Pro with Monterey.

I would appreciate any suggestions on what I can try next.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the target resource has a misconfigured certificate. Since there is no way to disable certificate verification in RDFLib - as far as I can tell - I have worked around the solution by requesting the resource via the python requests module with verify=False instead. Then I load the resource into RDFLib as text.